# how to use android mobile like emulator means how to connect my mobile via usb and run app. on it

Tags: android

I want to run an android application on my mobile. If it works on the emulator, then how would I connect my mobile via usb and make it work like the emulator out put?

Answer (score 1):

Here you find all information you need about setting up a real device for debugging:

[Using Hardware Devices](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)